# Cannot access session state across instances with Universal Session State Provider with SQL

Tags: azure, provider, universal, session-state

I have an Azure project that contains a web application. It runs with two instances in the compute emulator. I've added the universal provider for session state and am currently pointing it to a SQL Express database.

When a session is created I can see it being created in the database.

When I add something into the session state it appears to be stored into the database. I say appears because I haven't actually deserialized the data... I just see writes being made, and on the same instance the data deserializes fine.

The problem though is that if I happen to connect to the second instance the session data isn't available. If on the second instance I store data into the session, that then gets written to the database as a new session. Thing is, the session ID stays the same in the session cookie, but the database table creates new records for each instance:

SessionID in table:

0gong5ihsrjakfzry53e4rtm/LM/W3SVC/1273337584/ROOT
0gong5ihsrjakfzry53e4rtm/LM/W3SVC/1273337585/ROOT

For the sake of testing I tried changing the applicationName in the web.config and set cookieless=false.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you observed the same behaviour when you've deployed your application? I believe it's an issue that's been observed in the emulator, but on Azure itself, it works as expected.

See [this thread on the MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu-HU/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/3c41e920-67e8-4849-9b21-56fd7bfd0a5a) for a workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't apply to the new provider because it uses Entities instead of stored procs.